# How to Get the Middle Character from a string?

Tags: javascript

I am training on kata from CodeWars that can be found here https://www.codewars.com/kata/56747fd5cb988479af000028/train/javascript

I could not understand other solutions. My try is it:

```
const getMiddle = (s) => {
  let middle = ""
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if(s.length % 2 === 1) {middle = s[s.length-1/2]}
    if(s.length % 2 === 0) {middle = s[s.length-1/2-1] + s[s.length-1/2]}
  } return middle
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a loop? Just divide the length by 2, and use that as the index.

Comment: `s.length` is an integer, `1/2` is a fraction which is not an integer. You substract both, which will always result in a non-integer. You use the result as an index. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You never use `i`, that makes the loop very suspicious.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I think they mean `(s.length-1)/2`

Comment: Add anything that is relevant for this question in the question itself - like the actual task and at least one or two examples (input + expected output)

Comment: First of all, you should avoid loop, but if you really need a loop then you should try i.

Answer (score 3):

You're making this far more complicated than it needs to be.

You don't need a loop, since the length is not dependent on `i`.

Instead of checking whether the length is odd or even, you can just divide by 2 and round down.

```
function getMiddle(s) {
    return Math.floor(s.length / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`s.length / 2` will return number in `floating point` if the `s` length's is odd

```js
console.log(5 / 2);
console.log(6 / 2);
```

You have to parse it to int either using `parseInt`, or there is a shortcut that you can use as

```
(s.length / 2 - 1) | 0
```

```js
const a = 5 / 2;

console.log(parseInt(a));
console.log(a | 0);
```

```js
const getMiddle = (s) => {
  let middle = "";

  if (s.length % 2 === 1) middle = [s[(s.length / 2) | 0]];
  else middle = [s[(s.length / 2 - 1) | 0], s[(s.length / 2) | 0]];

  return middle.join("");
};

console.log(getMiddle("A"));
console.log(getMiddle("HELMO"));
console.log(getMiddle("HELLO0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not** iterate letters. You can simply do it for the `even` and `odd` lengths of strings.

```js
const getMiddle = (s) => {
  return s[Math.floor(s.length/2)]
}

console.log(getMiddle("abc"));
console.log(getMiddle("abcd"));
console.log(getMiddle("abcde"));
console.log(getMiddle("abcdef"));
console.log(getMiddle("abcdefg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to calculate the `pivot` and the `length` of the string.

```js
const expect = chai.expect;

class Test {
  static assertEquals(actual, expected) {
    return expect(actual).to.equal(expected);
  }
}

function getMiddle(s) {
  const pivot = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
  return s.length < 2
    ? s
    : s.length % 2 === 0
      ? s.substr(pivot - 1, 2)
      : s[pivot];
}

mocha.setup('bdd');

describe('GetMiddle', function() {
  it('Tests', function() {
    Test.assertEquals(getMiddle("test"),"es");
    Test.assertEquals(getMiddle("testing"),"t");
    Test.assertEquals(getMiddle("middle"),"dd");
    Test.assertEquals(getMiddle("A"),"A");
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/9.1.1/mocha.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/9.1.1/mocha.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/4.3.4/chai.min.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solutions:

```
function getMiddle(string) {

  let middle = Math.floor(string.length / 2);

  if (string.length % 2 === 0) {

      return string[middle - 1] + string[middle];
  }
  else{
      return string[middle];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We're looking to:

```
// find out if the string is even
// take its two middle characters in case it is
// OR
// if the string is odd, take its middle character
```

A string is even if dividing its length by two leaves no remainder:

```
s.length % 2 === 0
```

Now, given this statement, we have two options. One is to return two middle characters in case the string is in fact even.

```
s.slice(s.length / 2 - 1, s.length. / 2 + 1)
```

Because if a string is even, its middle is imaginary and the characters we want are one character away from this middle.

If the string is odd in characters, we have an actual middle made up of one character. Therefore, there is an index we can pull.

```
s[Math.floor(s.length / 2)]
```

where s has an index which we find by rounding down to the nearest integer the value of the string's length divided by two.

And so:

```
const getMiddle = s => {
  return s.length % 2 === 0
  ? s.slice(s.length / 2 - 1, s.length / 2 + 1)
  : s[Math.floor(s.length / 2)]
}
```

You can also write this as

```
const getMiddle = s => s.length % 2 === 0 ? s.slice(s.length / 2 - 1, s.length / 2 + 1) : s[Math.floor(s.length / 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void findMiddleLetterInString(){
        String name="middleLetter" ;
        int middleLetter;
        int i;
        for( i=0;i<name.length();i++){
            char stringtochar=name.charAt(i);
            middleLetter=name.length()/2;
            if(i==middleLetter) {
                System.out.println(stringtochar);
                System.out.println(middleLetter);

            }
        }        
        
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

So, as directed in the problem I have this suggestion you can try this It worked for me:

```
function getMiddle(s) {
if (s.length < 2) {
return s;
}
if (s.length % 2) {
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
if (i == (s.length - 1) / 2) {
return s[i];
}
}
} else {
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
if (i == s.length / 2) {
return s[i - 1] + s[i];
}
}
}
}
```

here we are checking for odd and even lengths as you may know if it is odd we simply return the middle value but for even we have to return 2 middle value

Comment: What does this answer add apart from regurgitating the other 7 existing answers? Minus formatting.